# About the decomposition of a rational prime $p$ in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_p, \zeta_m)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLpi9.png]

This is proposition 13.2.9 in Ireland and Rosen's "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory". $\zeta_n = e^{\frac{2\pi i}n}$.

Why does comparing with equation (*) give $f' \ge f, g' \ge g$? I think I showed it, but I only found a convoluted and long way, which I guess the authors didn't mean.

Comment: In the last 3 weeks you've asked 7 questions here about something from the algebraic number theory chapter of Ireland and Rosen. Do you have an advisor in your department to talk to about what you're reading?  If I were the advisor, I would strongly urge you to learn algebraic number theory from a proper book on the subject and only then see how I&R develop the topic.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, but my advisor recommended this book since the end goal is Eisenstein's reciprocity law (and not "actual" algebraic number theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\tilde{P}_j$ are the prime ideals of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ above $p$, and the $P_i$ are the prime ideals of $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p,\zeta_m)$ above $p$. But the  restriction of primes of $L$ to primes of $K$ is onto, so $\mathfrak{p} \in \{P_i,\, 1 \leq i \leq g\} \rightarrow \mathfrak{p} \cap K \in \{\tilde{P}_j,\, 1 \leq j \leq g’\}$ is onto. So $g \geq g’$. Every $\tilde{P}_j$ has degree $f$ and is the restriction to $K$ of some $P_i$ (which has degree $f’$), so $f’ \geq f$.

Comment: Thank you. Not that it really matters, but I believe you meant to write about the rings of integers (and not the fields).

Comment: @רוירז The ring of integers $R_K$ of a number field $K$ is determined by the field $K$. (This is in contrast to polynomial rings inside their fraction fields: you can't recover $\mathbf F_p[t]$ from knowing the field $\mathbf F_p(t)$ since you can write that field in other ways, such as $\mathbf F_p(1/t)$, and $\mathbf F_p[1/t] \not= \mathbf F_p[t]$.) This is why concepts that logically are about $R_K$ are very often spoken of as being associated to $K$: prime ideals of $K$, units of $K$, the discriminant of $K$, and the class group of $K$ are all understood to mean those concepts for $R_K$.

Comment: @KCd I see, thanks